# Remove element from list (Shorter version)

Tags: java

I made this code

```
final List<Future<?>> list = _scheduledTasks.remove(clazz);
        
if (Objects.nonNull(list))
{
    list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));
}
```

How can i make this into 1 line using java 8 style?

Comment: Technically, just remove the new lines and you have everything on one line and that'll still work.

Comment: What is `_scheduledTasks`? The first step should be making `_scheduledTasks.remove` return empty list instead of `null`.

Comment: What is `_schedulerTasks` and why are you checking `Objects.nonNull(list)` and filtering by `(Objects::nonNull)`? That looks redundant, but I am not sure...

Comment: Because the map might no contain that element so remove method will return null. But i made it using 1 line: Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz)).get().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));

Comment: @deHaar `Objects.nonNull(list)` checks if `remove(...)` returned null, i.e. if `list` is null. `Objects::nonNull` is checking if a list *element* is null. The first check is very valid, since `remove(...)` likely returns null when `clazz` is not found. The second check is probably unnecessary, since the list would likely never have null elements in it, but it could, depending on the logic that builds the list, and it doesn't hurt to make the check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 9+, use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) like this:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz))
        .stream() // Added in java 9
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));

// As "1 line"
Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz)).stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));
```

In Java 8, use [`ifPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-). A bit less elegant.

```java
Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz))
        .ifPresent(x -> x.stream()
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .forEach(s -> s.cancel(true)));

// As "1 line"
Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz)).ifPresent(x -> x.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> s.cancel(true)));
```

Comment: As i understand this line will work just fine as i read by the method's information. public void removeScheduledTask(final Class<?> clazz)
 {
  Optional.ofNullable(_scheduledTasks.remove(clazz)).get().stream().forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));
 }

Comment: @KbantikiMixaniki Javadoc of [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) says: *"Throws `NoSuchElementException` if there is no value present"*. That isn't much different than `scheduledTasks.remove(clazz).stream().forEach(s -> s.cancel(true));` which just throws `NullPointerException` instead.

Comment: Oh, you're right i just saw. So i need use the ifPresent